# Makefile automatic variables

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm working on a library of (more or less random ) c functions that I use in projects. The previous incarnation of it had every .c, .o file listed and manually compiled in target:

```
$(CC) $(SRCDIR)/somefoo.c $(CFLAGS) ... -c -o $(OBJDIR)/somefoo.o
```

This became tiresome, inaccurate and a pain, and I wanted to create a friendlier, better Makefile I could use for any project. After googling, reading( O'Reily's "Managing Projects with GNU Make ) and thinking I came up with:

```
BIN = /usr/bin

SH  = $(BIN)/bash
CC  = $(BIN)/cc
AR  = $(BIN)/ar
RL  = $(BIN)/ranlib
RM  = $(BIN)/rm
CP  = $(BIN)/cp
RL  = $(BIN)/ranlib
TC  = $(BIN)/touch
MK  = $(BIN)/make
FND = $(BIN)/find
TAR = $(BIN)/tar
RM  = $(BIN)/rm

CFLAGS  = -Wall -Wextra -Wpedanitc -pedanitc-errors\
          -w -Waddress -Walloc-zero -Walloca -Warray-bounds\
          -Wno-deprecated -Wno-div-by-zero -Werror -Wfatal-errors\
          -Wduplicated-cond -Wduplicated-branches -Wlogical-op -Wdouble-promotion\
          -Wrestrict -Wnull-dereference -Wjump-misses-init -Wshadow\
          -Wformat=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -pedantic --std=c99 --march=native
DEBUG   = -g -ggdb -gstabs
OPTIM   = -faggressive-loop-optimizations -fassociative-math -O3
LIBS    = -lm -lcommonC #add more here
INC     = -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I$(INCDIR)
LIBPATH = -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -L$(LIBDIR)
MKFLAG  = -f

PACK = $(TAR) -cvs
EXTRACT = $(TAR) -xf

PREFIX = /path/to/project #root directory of the project
BINDIR = $(PREFIX)/bin #stores Makefile, shell scripts, README, LICENSE, data files...
INCIDR = $(PREFIX)/include #holds .h files for the project
SRCDIR = $(PREFIX)/src #holds source files
OBJDIR = $(PREFIX)/obj #holds generated object files
LIBDIR = $(PREFIX)/lib #holds generated or included .a files
EXEDIR = $(PREFIX)/exe #generated executable(s)
DESTDIR ?= #where the tar file will be unpacked, user defined.

SRC = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c) #all .c source files
OBJ = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c)) #.o files
LIB ?= $(wildcard $(LIBDIR)/*.a) #the .a
EXE = $(EXEDIR)/project #generated executable
MKE = $(BINDIR)/Makefile #Makefile, used for cleaning before packing the project
TARF ?= #tar file for project.tar, user defined

.PHONY: obj exe update test clean pack install

# up to $(EXE) updated thanks to "Renaud Pacalet"
obj: $(OBJ)
exe: $(EXE)

$(OBJ): %.o: %.c
  $(CC) $< $(CFLAGS) $(LIB) $(INC) $(LIBPATH) $(LIBS) $(OPTIM) -c -o $@

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
   $(CC) $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIB) $(INC) $(LIBPATH) $(LIBS) $(OPTIM) -o $@

update: $(SRC)
    $(TC) $(SRC)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJ) $(EXE) $(LIB)

pack:
    $(MK) $(MKFLAG) $(MKE) clean && $(PACK) $(PREFIX) $(TARF)

install:
    cd $(DESTDIR) && $(TAR) $(EXTRACT) $(TARF)
```

My question is with the declaration of SRC, OBJ, and the target to compile .c -> .o The SRC = ... works fine, but for some reason the corresponding obj file is not being generated? Thank you for any and all input.

Update: Thanks to Renaud Pacalet, I have the OBJ/SRC variables figured out. I have been receiving an error:

```
make: Nothing to be done for 'obj'
```

Which usually means that the targets are up to date. It was brought to my attention that there is a lack of detail concerning my organization, so I added comments describing what each variable references. I have used this organization scheme before for most of my projects, and I have not had an issue with this until now.

Thank you for any and all input.

--Jordan.

-- Jordan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What gets created by your compilation rule is the result of the expansion of `$@`, that is the target of the rule, that is... `obj`. So you probably have a file named `obj` containing the result of the compilation of the first source in `$(SRC)` (expansion of `$<`). Use a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules), instead:

```
SRC = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
OBJ = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC))

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $< $(CFLAGS) $(LIB) $(INC) $(LIBPATH) $(LIBS) $(OPTIM) -c -o $@
```

Or a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
$(OBJ): %.o: %.c
    $(CC) $< $(CFLAGS) $(LIB) $(INC) $(LIBPATH) $(LIBS) $(OPTIM) -c -o $@
```

If what you wanted was a shorthand named `obj` for the compilation of all sources, you can define a [phony target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets):

```
.PHONY: obj

obj: $(OBJ)
```

and invoke:

```
make obj
```

Similarly, it would probably be better to define `exe` as phony and write a rule that explicitly creates a file. Make is always happier when the world it sees is made of recipes that create files:

```
.PHONY: exe

exe: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIB) $(INC) $(LIBPATH) $(LIBS) $(OPTIM) -o $@
```

One last note: you use `make` in one of your recipes (`pack`) through one of your `MK` custom variable. You should really consider replacing `MK` by the already defined [`MAKE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-MAKE) make variable:

```
pack:
    $(MAKE) $(MKFLAG) $(MKE) clean && $(PACK) $(PREFIX) $(TARF)
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunate, it just keeps saying "nothing to be done for obj". I renamed the directory to object so there was no name clash.

Comment: An `object` directory? Did I miss something or is it the first time you mention this?

Comment: My project directory trees usually have a directory called bin (for Makefiles, scripts, etc...), src(source files), obj(object files), exe(executables), lib(included/generated library's), include(for .h files)

Comment: @Jordan: Your organization looks good and clean. As it has a great impact on make's behavior and on how to write Makefiles you could, maybe, add all missing information to your question. Understanding why `it just keeps saying "nothing to be done for obj"` would be easier with a complete description of the files organization, from where you invoke make...